# How to aggregate string counts in spark(java) with datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I have a DataSet with the following structure

`+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
 | content            |         entities   |                  id|topic|
 +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+`

entities is a List of Strings, named entities, and topic is an integer.

I want to sum up the appearances of each distinct entity in a topic.

My first step is

`table.groupBy("topic");`

Then I want to aggregate, but how can I do that, I tought about implementing an custom aggregator, but then I need an Encoder for `Map<String,Integer>` which I don't know how to create.

How can I do this aggregation?

Comment: To be sure: entities is a list, so i.e. id=1, entities=a,b,c; id=2, entities: b, e, f, r?

Comment: yes, exactly this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you **exactly** want to calculate, but both options I can see requires **the same function** to be used.

Ok, test data:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val list = Seq((1, "topic1", Array("a", "b", "c", "b")), (2, "topic1", Array("b", "c", "r")), (3, "topic2", Array("e", "b", "c", "e")), (4, "topic2", Array("b", "c", "e", "r")))
val df = sc.parallelize(list).toDF("id", "topic", "entities");
```

## Calculating how many entities are of each type in each topic:

```
df
    .withColumn("entity", explode('entities))
    .groupBy('topic, 'entity)
    .count()
    .show();
```

Results will be:

```
+------+------+-----+
| topic|entity|count|
+------+------+-----+
|topic1|     a|    1|
|topic1|     b|    3|
|topic1|     c|    2|
|topic1|     r|    1|
|topic2|     b|    2|
|topic2|     c|    2|
|topic2|     e|    3|
|topic2|     r|    1|
+------+------+-----+
```

## How many distinct entities have each topic:

```
df
    .withColumn("entity", explode('entities))
    .groupBy('topic)
    .agg(countDistinct('entity))
    .show();
```

Results will be:

```
+------+-------------+
| topic|count(entity)|
+------+-------------+
|topic1|            4|
|topic2|            4|
+------+-------------+
```

## Key of answer

You should use explode function to create many rows for each entities column; entities = a,b,c will create 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are just counting the total number of entities per topic, then you can use the count functionality instead of having to write a custom aggregator. Coming straight from the Spark tutorial: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html:

```
table.groupBy("topic").count().show();
```

Comment: No, I want to sum up the count for each entity in a topic. Clarified the question a bit